# Create dictionary with tickers as keys and values as stock prices

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, yfinance

Is there a better way to achieve what the code below does? The list 'tickers' is a combination of stock tickers (e.g. AAPL, IBM)

```
list1 = tickers
list2 = []
dct = {}
count = 0

for i in tickers:
    list2.extend(yf.Ticker(i).history(period='7d')['Close'])
    dct[i] = list2[count:]
    count+=7
```

Comment: What do you mean by yf?

Comment: Is list2 something you need externally or just something needed for the computation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `len(yf.Ticker(i).history(period='7d')['Close'])==7`, it seems redundant to extend a list and then slice off the items appended to the list. So instead of the convoluted loop, use a dict comprehension:

```
dct = {i: yf.Ticker(i).history(period='7d')['Close'] for i in tickers}
```

As an explicit loop:

```
dct = {}
for i in tickers:
    dct[i] = yf.Ticker(i).history(period='7d')['Close']
```

Comment: There seems to be a count variable that slices the list as well

Comment: @SPSharan in each iteration, `list2` is extended by a list of length 7, and `count` used to slice the last 7 elements, which are precisely the elements added in the previous line

Comment: thanks @enke, how would I do that with a loop instead?

Comment: @Tom please see the update